# Can't type capital C in bash emacs line-edit mode

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble typing capital C into my shell console although i have no such problem when setting the input mode to vi or in the emacs editor itself.

```
set -o vi

emacs -nw
```

But have the problem when i do

```
set -o emacs
```

I've also removed the .emacs file from my home directory

Comment: This isn't an Emacs question, right? The problem is purely to do with the Emacs-style line editing support in bash?

Comment: I'm pretty stumped at this point about how i should go bout fixing this.

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? Typing a capital 'C' works fine for me with `GNU bash, version 4.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 3):

You have a key binding that's incorrect.

Assuming that this happens with new terminals, the binding is likely in your `~/.inputrc` file. Without seeing its contents, I can only guess. Look in that file and see if there's a line similar to this one (it could be any command on the right side of the colon):

```
"\C-q": menu-complete
```

and see if the backslash is missing. The backslash-C represents the control key.

You can rename the file and start a new terminal as a quick way to test if it's the culprit.